# Image rotation error using PIL because of exif metadata of images

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library

I am trying to stop auto-rotation of the images in a particular folder. As I'm using win7 64 bit in folder it says all correct once its uploaded to dropbox.

The rotation of image from 90 to 180 degree displays. With this python 3 code I'm  trying to achieve the 90 auto rotation for all my images in the folder. However I am getting this error. Please check and let me know how could I achieve this.

Here is the code that I am applying to it:

```
from PIL import Image
import os

image1 = Image.open('.JPG')
image1.rotate(90).save('.JPG')
```

Following is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dell 2\Desktop\14th Feb., 2020\183ND750\pil_demo.py", line 4, in <module>
    image1 = Image.open('.JPG')
  File "C:\Users\Dell 2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2809, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.JPG'
```

Comment: You can auto-rotate images far more simply with **ImageMagick**. Try making a **copy** of a directory of images and change directory to where the copies are in a Command Prompt. Then run `magick mogrify -auto-orient *.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

You're not giving it an image to work with. `('.JPG')` doesn't open an image in the folder. You want to pass a file path. Something like.

```
from PIL import Image
import os

image1 = Image.open('C:\Users\YourUser\Desktop\pics\my_image.jpg')
image1.rotate(90).save('C:\Users\YourUser\Desktop\pics\my_image.jpg')
```

Those calls to `open()` and `save()` interact with your computer's file system.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Actually i want to perform the task on a complete folder not an image. I get these images in Size of GBs every day.

Comment: That won't call every file in a complete folder, only individual files. And I don't think `.JPG` is a valid directory anyway.

Comment: user3127647: You will have to iterate through each JPG image file in the directory and explicitly rotate each one. It's unclear how what you want to do relates to exif metadata at all.